# ios dev - shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method not called for portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ios

In my rootViewController, I re-implemented the method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` like this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            NSLog(@"Orientation - Portrait");
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:          
            NSLog(@"Orientation - Left");
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            NSLog(@"Orientation - Right");
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            NSLog(@"Orientation - UpsideDown");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

When I rotate my device, this method is called for LandscapeRight, LandscapeLeft and UpsideDown, but not for the Portrait orientation.

At the launch the view is in portrait mode, and this method is called with UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait. But when I rotate the device this method is not called only for this orientation.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is normally only called once to tell the caller, what orientations the app will support (an ORed value or YES for all). You might be looking for `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to check the orientation and/or do some rearrangements before displaying the new orientation.

Comment: I want to rotate the central UIImageView in my main view without rotating all the interface.